# How to convert 1.5xxE-5

Tags: php, numbers, rounding

I have the number 1.5020370483398E-5 but I want to show it as 0.00001502037. How can I convert 1.5020370483398E-5 to that number? Regular rounding functions do not work and instead just output 0.

Comment: Just convert it to a string first? e.g. `echo "0.00001502037";`

Comment: @CD001 I am working with microtime which outputs numbers like above. Converting to string won't help here. But the answer below did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `number_format()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Here is an example on your case :

```
$test = 1.5020370483398E-5;

// Output : 0.00001502037
echo number_format($test, 11);
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I looked for! :)